# NoMethodError with MacRuby call to objective-c method

Tags: objective-c, macruby

I'm trying to call and objective-c method from a MacRuby application and it works fine as long as I only have one variable in the method. If I add a second variable I get a NoMethodError.

I have a feeling this is something small, but I can't seem to figure it out.

This is the method that works:

`- (int)testMethod:(int) x`

and this is the one that doesn't:

`- (int)testMethod:(int) x secondVariable:(int)y`

When I call the first method through the MacRuby testClass.testMethod(1) everything works well but when I call the second I get:
in `test_command': undefined method`testMethod' for :testClass (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for the second method in latest MacRuby should be the following:

```
testClass.testMethod(x, secondVariable:y)
```